# Spring boot / quartz webapp doesn't publish the "actuator/quartz" endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot web app with the quartz dependencies, and spring actuator running. But actuator only publishes 14 endpoints. Is there something I need to enable to get actuator to publish the quartz endpoint?

The parent project is

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>
```

And with the following spring dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the following actuator properties:

```
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
management.endpoint.quartz.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Despite the quartz dependency, there are no spring actuator endpoints published for quartz. The /actuator endpoint reports the following:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "beans": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/beans",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches-cache": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/caches/{cache}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "caches": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/caches",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health-path": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "info": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/info",
            "templated": false
        },
        "conditions": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/conditions",
            "templated": false
        },
        "shutdown": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown",
            "templated": false
        },
        "configprops": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/configprops",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/env",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env-toMatch": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/env/{toMatch}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "loggers": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers-name": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/{name}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "heapdump": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/heapdump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "threaddump": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/threaddump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics-requiredMetricName": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "metrics": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics",
            "templated": false
        },
        "scheduledtasks": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/scheduledtasks",
            "templated": false
        },
        "mappings": {
            "href": "https://localhost:8080/actuator/mappings",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot 2.4.0 and the Quartz endpoint is [new in Spring Boot 2.5.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#quartz). You should upgrade to 2.5 to use it.